# My phone didn't ring "because it was out of battery" or "because of being out of battery" or "out of battery"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

Which is the most natural way to say?
Or do all of them sound awkward?

Comment: My phone didn't ring because the battery was dead.

Comment: Or the battery was flat.

Comment: Or it was out of charge.

Comment: Or "... had run flat" or "... had gone flat".

Comment: Or "out of juice".

Answer (score 1):

None of your examples are correct. The **battery** doesn't disappear, it just loses **power**.

- "My phone's battery is **discharged**."
- "My phone's battery is out of power."
- "My phone's battery is dead." [colloquial]
- "My phone's battery is out of juice." [colloquial]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it also natural to say "My phone's dead." or "My phone died." or "The battery ran out." ?

Comment: Yes, those three are all colloquial English. Though nowadays, there's probably a "text speak" or "chat speak" acronym for dead battery. Perhaps, YWGTTBD: *You won't get this text, battery dead"?

Comment: discharged is a false friend of some kin. I think you mean: not charged or uncharged.

Comment: @Lambie, no, *discharged* is correct formal and colloquial English for a rechargeable battery that has lost power. However, it *can* also mean "dismissed," or "let go," as in, "He was discharged from the army."

Comment: In a technical environment, batteries can be said to be discharged, but it is not a term on uses in everyday speech: https://www.upsbatterycenter.com/blog/happens-battery-discharge-cycle/#:~:text=A%20battery's%20discharge%20cycle%20is,define%20a%20battery's%20expected%20life.&text=The%20discharge%20cycle%20is%20completed,voltage%20to%20power%20a%20load.

Comment: . What Constitutes a Discharge Cycle?
A discharge/charge cycle is commonly understood as the full discharge of a charged battery with subsequent recharge, but this is not always the case. Batteries are seldom fully discharged, and manufacturers often use the 80 percent depth-of-discharge (DoD) formula to rate a battery.//not everyday speech//https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/discharge_methods#:~:text=What%20Constitutes%20a%20Discharge%20Cycle,formula%20to%20rate%20a%20battery.